# Python Windows7: Odd behaviour opening file for append

Tags: windows-7, file-io, subprocess, python

I am seeing odd behaviour when I open a file in append mode ('a+') under Windows 7 using Python.

I was wondering whether the behaviour is in fact incorrect or I am misunderstanding how to use the following code:

```
log_file= open(log_file_path, "a+")
return_code = subprocess.call(["make", target], stdout=log_file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
log_file.close()
```

The above code lines does not properly append to the file. In fact on subsequent runs it won't even modify the file.
I tested it out using the Python Shell as well.
Once the file has been opened for the first time, making multiple subprocess calls will append properly to the file, however once the file has been closed and reopened it will never append again.

Anyone have any clues?

Thanks

---

To further simply the problem Here is another set of steps that will fail:

```
log_file=open("temp.txt", "a+")
log_file.write("THIS IS A TEST")
log_file.close()
log_file=open("temp.txt", "a+")
subprocess.call(["echo", "test"], stdout=log_file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
log_file.close()
```

If you open the file temp.txt here is what I see:

> test
> S A MUTHER F****** TEST

Comment: I've updated my answer below to reflect the new information you posted, minus the swearing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in the use of shell=True.  From [Python documentation for POpen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> On Unix, with shell=True: If args is a string, it specifies the
>   command string to execute through the shell. This means that the
>   string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the
>   shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash
>   escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a sequence, the
>   first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will
>   be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

So it looks like "echo" is the command, and "test" gets sent as an argument to the shell, instead of to "echo".

So changing your subprocess call to either:

```
subprocess.call("echo test", stdout=log_file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

or:

```
subprocess.call(["echo", "test"], stdout=log_file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Fixes the problem, at least in my testing.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as clearly he needs to use `subprocess`

Comment: Clearly, but it would help narrow the problem down to the subprocess call or the open/write/close calls.

Comment: ...which is best put in a comment, as it doesn't solve the question, and thus is not an answer, IMO.

Comment: so taking subprocess out of the equation doesn't exhibit the same problem.

Comment: I've added an edit to my original question to show an even simpler version of how it is failing.

Comment: You're correct @brc, but unfortunately I didn't have comment privilege when I posted this.  I will be more careful in the future now that I do.

Answer (score 1):

see http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-October/1221841.html

briefly: opening a file in append mode leaves the file ptr in an implementation-dependent state.  seek to the end to get the same results on windows as on linux.